# powershell: find all strings matching pattern in a file

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am looping through all files matching the pattern `maint-*.js`.

These files contains tokens in the form of `__MyTokenA__`, `__MyTokenB__`, etc...so I would like to find all of these tokens. I've tried the regex below, but it doesn't find anything.
I'd like to store the tokens in an array. What would be the correct way ?

```
$files = Get-ChildItem dist/main-*.js


 Foreach ($file in $files)
 {
    $matches = $file | Select-String ', "(?:\(__\))(.*?)(?:\(__\))"' -AllMatches
    echo $matches
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simplyfy your regex, then enumerate the matches property.

```
$file | Select-String '__(.*?)__' -AllMatches | ForEach-Object {
    $_
    $_.Matches | Select-Object Value
}
```